# primeng editor source code not working in angular 5

Tags: angular5, primeng

When tried to edit source code in primeng  tag, It is only editing one line at a time and without an html showing html tag also.
For example if I write "**Text is bold**", and when I clicked it on p-editor's *ql-code-block*
The expected values are to be shown in textarea is < p>< strong>Text is bold< /strong>< /p>.
Actual value shown in textarea is as follows:
Before :
[Before selection of ql-code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Sdz.png)
After :
[After selection of ql-code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pbL7.png)
Also after unselecting the ql-code-block button it removes the actual bold font of the text as follows :
[After unselection of ql-code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsXXw.png)
Please help me out in this.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are saying, the answer is that you can't have bold in a code-block section (ql-bold or ql-code-block, not both).

Comment: In short, I want to say is how to add html source code button which will edit/update the html tag. like any other wysiwyg editor.